# Google Cloud Messaging vs Firebase

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Suppose I have an application in which people suscribes to receive a notification when some event in a bar is created. I would also like to draw an icon in a google map when a bar is added. I read about Google Cloud Messaging and also Firebase which Google advertises as the improved version of the former. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: Nothing. Google bought firebase and renamed GCM to FCM. (A long time ago GCM was called C2DM)

Comment: Yes but both are available at present. I read that firebase is maybe more expensive. On the other hand I am afraid of developing in GCM and then it becomes deprecated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes No Difference as you read, Google Cloud Messaging is the traditional way to send push notifications and downstream message to Android.

Now with the addtional of new product Firebase (bought), google making some changes for efficient use. So they just renamed GCM as FCM (new improved version), along the change now you using FCM can send push notifications to iOS devices as well and more new features,

In fact you can register push token using Firebase and send api signal to GCM server, still the message would reach the device.

You can read this FAQ, https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm

Comment: But is GCM going to be deprecated? I am afraid of developing in GCM and then having to migrate to Firebase

Comment: We were using GCM in one of our application , and the only change in server side is just the api endpoint URL (from gcm to firebase), also for sure there will be a long deprecation time at time point nothing was mentioned and If you are starting fresh start with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for your experience input!

Comment: GCM is not being deprecated, it is still being fully supported. However while GCM and FCM are similar in feature set now new features will be added to FCM and unlikely to GCM. Also consider that FCM is part of Firebase which means it plays nicely with the other Firebase APIs, for example FCM can log Firebase analytics events for message opens automatically. So feel free to continue using GCM, but FCM is easier and more powerful and that gap will likely continue to get larger.

Answer (score 4):

**Google Cloud Messaging is DEPRECATED 4/10/2018!**

As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and **will be removed as soon as May 29, 2019**. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the migration guide to learn more.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

**Why is GCM being deprecated?**

Simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.
Enables a new serverless notifications solution with a web console, the Firebase Notifications console. With the Notifications console, anyone can send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights. The console has deep integration with Google Analytics, Firebase predictions, and Firebase A/B testing.
Includes ongoing feature enhancements/updates such as the [HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/whats-new-with-fcm-customizing-messages.html).
Provides better delivery reporting and more reliable delivery